# Can't use hex codes for coloring <a> tags?

Tags: html, css, colors

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    <title>Register to Continue</title>
    <!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
    <!-- Code above created to stop the IE9 Active X/Scripts Disabler -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main" class="main">
      <table class="container1">
        <tr>
          <td><p><img src="images/doesitfit.png" alt=""></p></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <div class="container2">
        <form accept-charset="utf-8"
              action="https://app.getresponse.com/add_contact_webform.html"
              method="post">
          <input type="text" 
                 placeholder="Enter Your First Name" 
                 class="form" 
                 name="name"><br/>
          <input type="text" 
                 placeholder="Enter Your Email" 
                 class="form" 
                 name="email"><br/>
          <input type="text" 
                 placeholder="Enter Your Phone Number" 
                 class="form" 
                 name="phone"><br/>
          <input type="submit" 
                 class="button" 
                 name="submit" 
                 value="">
          <input type="hidden" 
                 name="webform_id" 
                 value="540572" />
        </form>
        <footer id="footer">
          <a href="http://armored-media.com/">Armored Media</a> | 
          <a href="http://intrack.us/ihs/">Internet Hustler Society</a> | 
          <a href="http://intrack.us/ms/">Magic Submitter</a> | 
          <a href="http://intrack.us/contact/">Contact</a>
          <script type="text/javascript"                 
                  src="http://app.getresponse.com/view_webform.js?wid=540572&mg_param1=1"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript"                          
                  src="http://app.getresponse.com/view_webform.js?wid=540572&mg_param1=1"></script>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
  background-color : rgba(11, 11, 11, 0.8);
  width : 800px;
  height : 550px;
  border-radius : 15px;
  margin-left : auto;
  margin-right : auto;
  min-height : 10em;
  height : 100%;
  overflow : hidden;
}
.container1 {
  table-layout : fixed;
  height : 50%;
  overflow : hidden;
  width : 802px;
  border-color : #ff0000;
  border-radius : 15px;
  margin-left : auto;
  margin-right : auto;
  min-height : 10em;
  color : white;
  margin : auto;
}
.form {
  font-size : 19px;
  border : solid 0;
  color : #7a7a7a;
  height : 28px;
  width : 295px;
  text-align : center;
  margin : 0 auto;
  display : block;
  border-radius : 15px;
  border : none;
  outline : none;
}
.button {
  border : none;
  background : url('images/button.png');
  background-repeat : no-repeat;
  height : 102px;
  width : 339px;
  border-radius : 15px;
  display : block;
  margin-left : auto;
  margin-right : auto;
}
a:link {
  color: yellow;
  font-size : 18px;
  text-decoration : none;
}
a:visited{
  color: yellow;
  font-size : 18px;
  text-decoration : none;
}
a:active{
  color: yellow;
  font-size : 18px;
  text-decoration : none;
} 
footer {
  text-align : center;
}
```

Whenever I use hex code values for my  tags in CSS, it never works. They just go back to blue. I've used hex codes before, but why is it not working this time? Using the default color names do not help me much in my effort to style them good.

Comment: When posting a question in stackoverflow, try posting only the relevant part. Don't just copy&paste your **entire** HTML and CSS. It makes your question really unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding

```
a {
    color: #f4f7f8;
}
```

Hex worked correctly

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9xmRN/

Comment: @Travis, I've seen you using my answer in another question, to choose an answer and close the question click the 'Check' image left to the answer, under /\ 0 \/.

Comment: yeah! This is the waay you need to give color for Anchor tag